# Multiplication of inputs & sum of inputs using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to write an application where we have a HTML table with 4 rows (for simplicity's sake) & 3 columns.

The first 2 columns are inputs & the 3rd will display the result of multiplying these inputs (for each row), the I would like the 3rd column in the final row to calculate the sum of the results in column 3.

I am thinking I need to write a JavaScript function to iterate over the entire table but what I am unsure of is how to label the inputs - does each one need to be different?

```
<table width="80%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Column 1</th>
        <th>Column 2</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" onchange="calculate()" /></td>
        <td><input id="result" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" onchange="calculate()" /></td>
        <td><input id="result" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" onchange="calculate()" /></td>
        <td><input id="result" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" /></td>
        <td><input id="???" type="text" onchange="calculate()" /></td>
        <td><input id="result" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You cannot have more than one element with an `id` of "result", for instance.

Comment: They need to be different depending on what you actually want to do. I'd drop the `onchange` attribute and create a selector for your table's inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to set id. With jquery I would try something like:

```
function calculate() {
    var tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    var inputs = tr.find("input");
    var input1 = $(inputs[0]);
    var input2 = $(inputs[1]);
    var resultInput = $(inputs[2]);
    resultInput.val(+input1.val()+input2.val()); // +input1.val() is cast input1 to number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, give your ID name unique.

You can use `parseInt()` to calculate the sum or multiplication

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("id-one").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("id-two").value);
var sum = a+b;
var mul = a*b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline HTML for javascript. Instead create a selector like:

```
$('table input').change(function() { }
```

You can use `$(this)` inside the function to manipulate the current input changed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply - this looks like the solution I'm looking for could you elaborate a little pls?